# NextJS custom 404 page is not showing up

Tags: typescript, next.js, http-status-code-404

I have the `404.tsx` file in the `apps/specificapp/pages/` directory, but NextJS still displays the default pre-generated 404 page.

Am I misunderstanding the documentation, or is something preventing me to override the default 404 page?

Comment: As long as the file is correctly named and in the right place, e.g. `/pages/404.tsx`, that should be enough. Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @juliomalves I just created a new project with create-next-app, using TS, but the issue is not there, the custom 404 works just fine, while in the existing project it doesn't.
Sadly the existing project is huge and way beyond my understanding, so I wouldn't know which parts would be worth putting in an example, much less which parts I can actually share here, since it's a company project.

Answer (score 3):

So as it turns out the `next.config.js` configured to project to only accept the file extensions `page.tsx`, `page.ts`, `page.jsx` and `page.js`. I changed my filename to `404.page.tsx` and it's working perfectly now.